# How to center an image in a rectangle?

Tags: c#, image, xna, center

How do you center an image inside a rectangle with:

```
Batch.draw(imagename, new Rectangle(x, y, imagename.width, imagename.height), Color.White);
```

Comment: I know I already answered this, but please provide more context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the origin overload for spritebatch

```
Batch.draw(imagename, new Rectangle(x, y, imagename.width, imagename.height), Color.White,0f,new Vector2(imagename.Width /2, imagename.Height /2) ,SpriteEffects.Null, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the overloads for [`SpriteBatch.Draw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433991.aspx) asks for a `Texture2D` (the image), a `Vector2` (the position of the image), and a `Color` (the tint of the image). You should not have to use a rectangle for drawing your image. Just use some math to get the correct `X` and `Y` values for the position.

You will have to take into consideration the height/width of the image, and the height/width of the containing object (like the screen or something).

Another option is to use an overload that takes the `Origin` parameter. Set this to the *relative* center of your image. This will change the "draw origin" of the image from the top-left to the center.